# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to run this code but I keep on getting this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I don't understand what it means or why I'm getting it. Any hint?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var lastNumber: String = ""
@IBOutlet var answerField: UILabel
@IBOutlet var operaterLabel: UILabel

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(theButton: UIButton) {
    if answerField.text == "0"
    {
        answerField.text = theButton.titleLabel.text
    }
    else
    {
        answerField.text = answerField.text + theButton.titleLabel.text
    }
}

@IBAction func plusTapped(theButton: UIButton) {
    // error is talking about the next line
    if operaterLabel.text == ""
    {
        operaterLabel.text = "+"
        lastNumber = answerField.text
        answerField.text = "0"
    }
    else
    {
        enterTapped(nil)
        operaterLabel.text = "+"
    }

}

@IBAction func minusTapped(theButton: UIButton) {
    if operaterLabel.text == ""
    {
        operaterLabel.text = "-"
        lastNumber = answerField.text
        answerField.text = "0"
    }
    else
    {
        enterTapped(nil)
        operaterLabel.text = "-"
    }

}

@IBAction func clearTapped(AnyObject) {
    answerField.text = "0"
    operaterLabel.text = ""
    lastNumber = ""

}

@IBAction func enterTapped(AnyObject?) {

    var num1 = lastNumber.toInt()
    var num2 = answerField.text.toInt()
    if !num1 || !num2
    {
        showError()
        return
    }
    var answer = 0
    if operaterLabel.text == "-"
    {
        var answer = num1! - num2!
    }
    else if operaterLabel.text == "+"
    {
        var answer = num1! + num2!
    }
    else
    {
        showError()
        return
    }
    answerField.text = "\(answer)"

}

func showError()
{
    println("Ther was an error")
}
}
```

Comment: At which line is XCode running into the error?

Comment: This line: if operaterLabel.text == "" @jmduke

Comment: This must have been asked more times than "How do I pass data between view controllers?" :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the error refers to the fact that you're accessing the parameter of an optional value when the optional value is set to nil (e.g. accessing `answerField.text` when `answerField` is nil), likely one of your two `UILabels`.

If the line `operaterLabel.text == ""` is throwing the exception, then your `operaterLabel` is nil.  Verify that you have connected it successfully to the label in your Interface Builder file.

Comment: So if the erorr is highlighting this:  if operaterLabel.text == ""  in fuction plusTapped whats the problem

Answer (score 7):

some times the problem that you have initiate view controller before present it like this:

```
let myViewController  = MyViewController()
```

replace that by

```
let  myViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardID") as! MyViewController
```

Comment: I logged in to vote for this answer. This solved it in my case.

Comment: I've done a bit of research as to why this works. This threw me for a loop at first as I've persisted data using the top line of code when creating a view programmatically and not utilizing storyboard. It seems the view needs to be explicitly created utilizing storyboard for @IBOutlets to be linked to the UIViewController class. You can however use the top line of code if you are not utilizing storyboard for the ViewController you're creating an instance of.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I was trying to access the labels in a function that I created which was used after the set of a variable.

```
var something: String {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
}

func updateUI() {
    label.text = "Hello"
}
```

I solved it by:

```
var something: String

override func viewDidLoad() {
    label.text = "hello"
}
```

My theory is that my function updateUI was accessed before the views and labels were created.

Answer (score 5):

check your outlets, I've had this before labels and buttons can just become dis connected (if for instance you have adjusted constraints ect)

a simple re connection can sometimes fix the issue

Comment: You can do this by opening up the storyboard file and opening the connections inspector in the utility pane (circle with right arrow icon). The connections are listed (and can be created) under the "Referencing Outlets" section (XCode 7.1).

Answer (score 4):

If you make sure the `xib` for your cell is no problem,

Then I occur this issue, my error was register the `cell` method :

1)

```
self.tableView.register(TerantInfoTabCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TerantInfoTabCell")
```

2)

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName:"TerantInfoTabCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TerantInfoTabCell")
```

I use the first method, there will appear the issue,then I use the 2) method replace the 1) , so there is no problem here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error and spent quiet an amount of time debugging it. What @jmduke said is really the key: where does the error occur?

With my particular error, looking at `operaterLabel.text == ""` led me on the right path. I accessed the `operaterLabel.text` while the view was not yet fully initialized. In my particular case I set a variable from a different view during a segue and then acted upon that variable being set and updating a label inside the view. However the view was not completely initialized.

Thus my solution was to update the label inside the `viewDidLoad()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I searched and searched trying to figure out how to solve my similar problem. As others mentioned, I was accessing UI elements before they were initialized. But figuring out why, was the difficult part. Spoiler --> I was using ProfileVC.swift and profileVC.xib

Even though I had all of my connections right in IB, from the parentVC I was calling

```
let newVC = ProfileVC()
profile.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
present(profile, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

Since I had different names (caplital 'P' in my swift file and lowercase 'p' in my xib), calling ProfileVC() didn't work as it didn't know to go to the xib I had made.  Instead I had to use:

```
let newVC = ProfileVC.init(nibName: "profileVC", bundle: Bundle.main)
```

or just rename the xib to have a captial P and I could use my original code

Obviously this is hard to see in stackoverflow as you need to see what you are calling in the parent VC, the names of the files and IB. So hopefully this may be one solution to someone's problem out there even if it doesn't solve Arshia's problem.

Answer (score 0):

That means your storyboard doesn't have a link to your IBOUTLET, please verify

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and my problem was caused by adding a member (let's call it newProperty) to my model class, then trying to run a project that loaded data with NSCoder.decodeObjectForKey(newPropertyKey). During previous testing, I had saved objects without newProperty, so when the app tried to call decodeObjectForKey(newPropertyKey) on my old data, Xcode responded with this error message.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs because we try to change UILabel text after the view is loaded. Remember that UILabels once loaded in the view cannot be changed in any way they can only be set within viewdidload() function. You can check this by putting your text assigning code in the viewDidLoad() function which will set UILabels when loading the view, It will work. 
But now if your application is built in such a way that it is setting UILabels after the view is loaded then the only solution is that you will need to create UILabels dynamically/Programatically where ever you want in the code and assign what ever you want because they will be created/instantiated with that text/label.

Answer (score 0):

As  @aircraft said  you can register your cell this way  :

```
let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "\(CellClass.self)", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "\(CellClass.self)")
```

this solved the problem with me.