# SWIFT fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift

i'm trying to run this swift code but it outputs the following error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)".
This is the code:

```
 //
//  PlaySoundsViewController.swift
//  Revoice
//
//  Created by Leonardo Barazza on 16/04/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Leonardo Barazza. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie_quote", ofType: "mp3") {
            var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
            audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)
        } else {
            println("the filePath is empty")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func playSlowly(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may want to give more information where exactly the debugger breaks.  and gives you the error. In general, a nil is given where your code expected a non nil.

Comment: Do not explicitly unwrap things that can ever, under any circumstances be nil–unless you want crashes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948302/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is in `audioPlayer` property: it's defined as an implicitly unwrapped `AVAudioPlayer` optional, so it cannot be `nil` whenever you access it (otherwise a runtime exception is thrown, because of the implicitly unwrap).

The problem is that you actually create an instance (`audioPlayer != nil`) only if `filePath != nil`. Did you check that `filePath` is not nil?

By the way you can skip this problem by using optional chaining:

```
@IBAction func playSlowly(sender: UIButton) {
    if audioPlayer?.play() == nil {
        println("audioPlayer is nil")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code above the question, you created only one instance variable, `audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer` , with excalmatory mark `!`.

- The error will show when the complier use the instance which was not created yet.
- After read your code, only one place used the instance of `AVAudioPlayer`, `func playSlowly()`. But you did not show your debugger information, I can just guess `audioPlayer.play()` is the place where the error is.
- I think the code 
  `if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movie_quote", ofType: "mp3")` , leads to the failing to define the instance of `audioPlayer`.
- You should check whether the definition of `filePath` is correct.