# How to fix: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, social-networking

I am working on a Firebase Swift project using CocoaPods.

Every time after I log in the main ViewController, automatically I get `EXC_BREAKPOINT` error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

Here are some of my code lines where I got errors:

```
All codes from Joke.swift:

import Foundation
import Firebase


class Joke {
private var _jokeRef: Firebase!

private var _jokeKey: String!
private var _jokeText: String!


private var _jokeVotes: Int!


private var _username: String!

var jokeKey: String {
    return _jokeKey
}

var jokeText: String {
    return _jokeText
}

var jokeVotes: Int {
    return _jokeVotes //1
}

var username: String {
    return _username
}

// Initialize the new Joke

init(key: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    self._jokeKey = key

    // Within the Joke, or Key, the following properties are children

    if let votes = dictionary["votes"] as? Int {
        self._jokeVotes = votes
    }

    if let joke = dictionary["jokeText"] as? String {
        self._jokeText = joke
    }

    if let user = dictionary["author"] as? String {
        self._username = user
    } else {
        self._username = ""
    }

    // The above properties are assigned to their key.

    self._jokeRef = DataService.dataService.JOKE_REF.childByAppendingPath(self._jokeKey)
}



// Add or Subtract a Vote from the Joke.

func addSubtractVote(addVote: Bool) {

    if addVote {
        _jokeVotes = _jokeVotes + 1
    } else {
        _jokeVotes = _jokeVotes - 1
    }

    // Save the new vote total.

    _jokeRef.childByAppendingPath("votes").setValue(_jokeVotes)

  } 
}
```

In JokeCellTableViewCell.swift:

```
var joke: Joke!
...............

func configureCell(joke: Joke) {

        self.joke = joke

        // Set the labels and textView.

        self.jokeText.text = joke.jokeText
        self.totalVotesLabel.text = "Total Votes: \(joke.jokeVotes)" // 2
        self.usernameLabel.text = joke.username

        // Set "votes" as a child of the current user in Firebase and save the joke's key in votes as a boolean.

.........
}
```

And in the main ViewController, JokesFeedTableViewController.swift:

```
var jokes = [Joke]()

....................


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let joke = jokes[indexPath.row]

    // We are using a custom cell.

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("JokeCellTableViewCell") as? JokeCellTableViewCell {

        // Send the single joke to configureCell() in JokeCellTableViewCell.

        cell.configureCell(joke) // 3

        return cell

    } else {

        return JokeCellTableViewCell()

    }
   ...........
```

// 1, // 2, // 3 are code lines where errors appear.

I hope you could help me to fix this!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What's `_jokeVotes`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948302/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value)

Comment: @originaluser2 `var jokeVotes: Int {
        return _jokeVotes
    }` _jokeVotes is declared as Init

Comment: @Fonix, it's not right same.

Comment: Where do you initialise `_jokeVotes`?  Have you set a breakpoint and used the debugger to step through and see what is nil?

Comment: @Paulw11, I initialises `_jokeVotes` as Int at the top of the page: `private var _jokeVotes: Int!`. I used the debugger step by step to follow what's wrong, but it seems that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: That declares it as an implicitly unwrapped optional, but it doesn't initialise it. Since you made it an implicitly unwrapped optional with ! but never assigned a value you will get the exception when you,access it since you told Swift it wouldn't be nil with ! but it is

Comment: @Paulw11, if I delete the "!" from initialization, I get errors on other functions. I updated the whole 'Joke.swift'. What do you guess I should do?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between declaration and initialisation. What you have is a declaration, and the ! says that you will initialise it later; ie give it an initial value. But you haven't done that so it is nil and you get a crash. `var _jokeVotes=0` both declares *and* initialises the variable

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have not clearly defined the expectations of the `Joke` class.

Your initializer suggests that the properties on `Joke` should be optional, however, you are using them as though they are not. You must decide on which way you want to take it.

If the properties can be optional, I would suggest something like this:

```
class Joke {
    private let jokeReference: Firebase

    let jokeKey: String

    private(set) var jokeText: String?

    private(set) var jokeVotes: Int?

    let username: String

    // Initialize the new Joke

    init(key: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        jokeKey = key

        // Within the Joke, or Key, the following properties are children

        if let votes = dictionary["votes"] as? Int {
            jokeVotes = votes
        }

        if let joke = dictionary["jokeText"] as? String {
            jokeText = joke
        }

        if let user = dictionary["author"] as? String {
            username = user
        } else {
            username = ""
        }

        // The above properties are assigned to their key.

        jokeReference = DataService.dataService.JOKE_REF.childByAppendingPath(jokeKey)
    }
}
```

However, if the properties should never be `nil`, you need something like this:

```
class Joke {
    private let jokeReference: Firebase

    let jokeKey: String

    let jokeText: String

    let jokeVotes: Int?

    let username: String

    // Initialize the new Joke

    init?(key: String, dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {

        jokeKey = key

        guard let votes = dictionary["votes"] as? Int,
            joke = dictionary["jokeText"] as? String else {
                return nil
        }

        jokeText = joke
        jokeVotes = votes

        if let user = dictionary["author"] as? String {
            username = user
        } else {
            username = ""
        }

        // The above properties are assigned to their key.
        jokeReference = DataService.dataService.JOKE_REF.childByAppendingPath(jokeKey)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to replace it with something like that: 'private var jokeRef: Firebase!
private(set) var jokeKey: String!
private(set) var jokeText: String!
private(set) var jokeVotes: Int!
private(set) var username: String!'?