# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948302/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value) but that doesn't solve this problem for me. I've added a `tableView` in a `ViewController`. Made extended the class with it's dataSource and Delegate and added the required methods for it.
Then I made a prototype cell in this table (Not the separate .xib for it) and made a class for that `TableViewCell` and collected the `@IBOutlet`:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var titleOfAccount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastModified: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var accountImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellView: UIView!
```

Then in `cellForRowAt` method of table view when I wrote

```
cell.titleOfAccount.text = "Hello World"
cell.lastModified.text = "Last Modified: 21 May 2017"
```

and ran the code it crashed with this error.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What I did after searching here and there I went back to `tableViewCell` class and changed `!` to `?` and updated the code in `cellForRowAt` as:

```
 cell.titleOfAccount?.text = "Hello World"
 cell.lastModified?.text = "Last Modified: 21 May 2017"
```

Now when I ran the program it runs successfully but there is no cell appearing in the `tableView` and I've also implemented the method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3;
    }
```

Here is the full code of my `cellForRowAt` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: AccountsTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! AccountsTableViewCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.clipsToBounds = true

        cell.cellView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.cellView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        cell.cellView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        cell.cellView.layer.shadowRadius = 10

        cell.titleOfAccount.text = "Hello World"
        cell.lastModified.text = "Last Modified: 21 May 2017"
        cell.accountImage.image = UIImage(named: "fb")

        return cell
    }
```

P.S. I've also added `self.tableView.register(AccountsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)` in `viewDidLoad`

[image]
[image]

Comment: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AccountsTableViewCell

Comment: nope still the same error!

Comment: How you declare reusableidentifier??

Comment: And where you get crash??

Comment: Share snap shot of your Class & attribute inspection of storyboard/XIB. Also   confirm, are you using Storyboard or XIB based View Controller for designing your table view?

Comment: @KrunalBhavsar added the image. Also uploading the class image.

Comment: @Swift_Guru in `cellForRowAt` method and on `cell.cellView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor`

Comment: Ok how you declare your cellreusableidentifier?

Comment: @Swift_Guru kindly see the screenshot of code I've updated in the question you'll be able to see where I've declared it.

Comment: Is the class of the custom cell set to `AccountsTableViewCell` in Interface Builder? Do not register the cell if you are using storyboard.

Comment: remove the line that register class programatically

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From your `viewDidLoad()` remove following line (code), as you already have connected your Cell from story board.

```
self.tableView.register(AccountsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
```

Also share snapshot for identity inspector (just left side of attribute inspector).

Comment: Yes! I totally forgot this... #SwiftBeginners

Comment: coming from swfit 5, had the same issue. deleting the registration while already registered in interface builder, helped. Thanks. #SwiftBeginners

Answer (score 5):

I think you can resolve this by modify the code in the ViewController.

Use below

```swift
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "AccountsTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
```

instead of

```swift
self.tableView.register(AccountsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 :- Create UITableView Extension Class

```
//MARK: - UItableView Extension
extension UITableViewCell {
// Not using static as it wont be possible to override to provide custom storyboardID then
class var storyboardID : String {
    return "\(self)"
  }

static func registerCellXib(with tableview: UITableView){
    let nib = UINib(nibName: self.storyboardID, bundle: nil)
    tableview.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.storyboardID)
  }
}
```

Step 2 :- In ViewDidLoad method register cell

```
AudioTableViewCell.registerCellXib(with: audioListTableView)
```

here AudioTableViewCell is tableviewCell and audioListTableView is Tableview

Step 3 :- In CellForRowAt index method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: AudioTableViewCell.storyboardID, for: indexPath) as! AudioTableViewCell
    cell.audioFileName.text = "Audio \(indexPath.row + 1)"
    
    return cell
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourcellidentifier", for: indexPath) as! AccountsTableViewCell
          // add your code
    }
```

Comment: No still getting the same: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: check you cell identifier with storyboard please it should be the same of "yourcellidentifier"

Comment: just checked it's the same at both ends `accountCell`

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same problem, and this works for me:

```
// old code
// self.tableView.register(YourTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourCellReuseIdentifier")

// new code
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: YourTableViewCell, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourCellReuseIdentifier")
```